# SQL How to Combine Rows into One

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot-table

I have this data from the query:

```
SELECT Match.MatchID, [Set].SetValue, Game.GameValue
FROM Game INNER JOIN
 [Set] ON Game.SetID = [Set].SetID INNER JOIN
 Match ON [Set].MatchID = Match.MatchID
 ORDER BY Match.MatchID, [Set].SetValue, Game.GameValue desc
```

[image]

What I want to achieve is the following result:

[image]

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Images of something that might be data and no explanation of how to get from input to desired results doesn't help us help you.

Comment: Obviously someone was able to answer my question so it wasn't that bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select s.matchid,
       concat(max(case when s.setvalue = 1 then g.gamevalue end), '-',
              min(case when s.setvalue = 1 then g.gamevalue end)
             ) as set1,
       concat(max(case when s.setvalue = 2 then g.gamevalue end), '-',
              min(case when s.setvalue = 2 then g.gamevalue end)
             ) as set2     
from Game g join
     [Set] s
     on g.SetID = s.SetID 
group by s.matchid;
```